# PHP autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ms-access

I trying to fine tune an autocomplete text box.  What I have here works (albeit a bit messy). But I would like to display the values available when clicking into the text box, then filter down as you type. Also, is there a simpler way to code this?

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) {
$User =  $_SESSION['myusername'];}

$db1 = realpath('C:\AccessBackEnds\CETracker\CETracker.accdb');
$conn1 = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$db1",'','') or die ("Unable to connect to server");

?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../datepicker/jquery-ui2.css" />
<script src="../datepicker/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../datepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTasks = [
<?php
$info0 = "SELECT DISTINCT TaskName FROM CT:MyTasks WHERE UserName = '$User'";
$rs0=odbc_exec($conn1,$info0);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs0)) {
$TaskName = "" . $row['TaskName'] . "";
echo '"';
echo $TaskName;
echo '", ';
}
?>""];
$( "#Tasks" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTasks
});
});
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="Tasks">Tasks: </label>
<input name="tasks" id="Tasks" style="width: 400px">
</div>
```

Comment: You really need to be careful to [properly escape all your user data](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid nasty [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). `$User` here is injected directly in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could enhance the readibility of your script if your split it in two files:

- A frontend file, that one has HTML and JS code
- A backend file, which has PHP code that generate JSON code.

The frontend file can call the backend file by a json invocation, take into account that the "Autocomplete" widget of jQuery UI has this functionlity built-in. Have a look [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in "Remote JSONP Source".
Also PHP can easily generate JSON data by [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.